# CannotPullContainerError when trying to deploy AWS multicontainer using elasticbeanstalk with eb cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, deployment, elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to deploy a simple docker image to AWS ElasticBeanstalk using `eb` cli, but I can't get the docker service to start in ECS due to the following error:

> invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

My `Dockerrun.aws.json` file:

```json
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "ipsec-vpn-server",
      "image": "hwdsl2/ipsec-vpn-server:latest",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 500,
          "containerPort": 500
        },
        {
          "hostPort": 4500,
          "containerPort": 4500
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My `.ebignore`

```
# Only keep Dockerrun.aws.json
*
!Dockerrun.aws.json
```

I attached the `AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker` role to `aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role`:

```bash
aws --profile my-profile-name \
iam attach-role-policy \
policy-arn arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker \
--role-name aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role
```

[image: AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker policy in aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role]

I created the aws eb environment like this:

```bash
export VPN_USER="some_secret_user"
export VPN_PASSWORD="some_secret_password"    
export VPN_IPSEC_PSK="some_secret_ipsec_psk"

eb create vpn-example \
--profile my-profile-name \
--region us-east-1 \
--platform multi-container-docker-17.09.1-ce-\(generic\) \
--envvars VPN_USER=${VPN_USER} \
--envvars VPN_PASSWORD=${VPN_PASSWORD} \
--envvars VPN_IPSEC_PSK=${VPN_IPSEC_PSK} \
--cname some-vpn-example-domain
```

Environment did create correctly, but as you can see, it's not healthy ;)

[image: eb environment]

The envionment creation runs for a while, creates load balencers, etc. But it fails after a while after trying to launch the task many times here in the ECS dashboard:

[image: ecs cluster]

When clicking on a single task, I see this:
[image: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase]

Status:

> STOPPED (CannotPullContainerError: API error (400): invalid)

Details Status Reason:

> CannotPullContainerError: API error (400): invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Latest event shows following warning in elastic beanstalk environment:

> Environment health has transitioned from Degraded to Severe. Command failed on all instances. ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.

`eb logs` has no output at all.

I don't use any uppercase letter in `containerDefinitions`'s `image`. The only weird thing I found is the `Image` column in the task that says `Dockerrun.aws.json` where I would expect it to be `hwdsl2/ipsec-vpn-server` (I think).

I also thought this would have been a service and not a task. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I can't seem to find a way to read the logs. I tried again from scratch and the logs for `eb create` command are the following:

```
WARNING: The Multi-container Docker platform requires additional ECS permissions. Add the permissions to the aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role or use your own instance profile by typing "-ip {profile-name}".
For more information see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html#create_deploy_docker_ecs_role
Creating application version archive "app-xxxx-xxxxxx_xxxxxx".
Uploading example-vpn/app-xxxx-xxxxxx_xxxxxx.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
Environment details for: vpn-dev-01
  Application name: example-vpn
  Region: us-east-1
  Deployed Version: app-xxxx-xxxxxx_xxxxxx
  Environment ID: e-mtwbaums2n
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Multi-container Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.0
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: example-vpn-SNIP.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2018-03-22 18:55:03.173000+00:00
Printing Status:
INFO: createEnvironment is starting.
INFO: Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-xxxxxxxxxxxx as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
INFO: Created security group named: sg-SNIP
INFO: Created security group named: awseb-e-SNIP
INFO: Created load balancer named: awseb-e-SNIP
INFO: Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-SNIP
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group named: awseb-SNIP
INFO: Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:SNIP
INFO: Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:SNIP
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-SNIP
INFO: Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-SNIP
ERROR: Failed to start ECS task: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:task/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx is STOPPED.
ERROR: ECS task stopped due to: Essential container in task exited. (ipsec-vpn-server: )
ERROR: Failed to start ECS task: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:task/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx is STOPPED.
ERROR: Failed to start ECS task after retrying 2 times.
ERROR: [Instance: i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: trying 2 times.' --severity ERROR
+ exit 1.
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/03start-task.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

I tried again with a different docker image `nginx:latest` and the service started so the problem I had was with [`hwdsl2/ipsec-vpn-server:latest`](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn) directly. I tried again but locally:

```bash
docker pull hwdsl2/ipsec-vpn-server:latest
eb local run --debug
```

And it showed me the error:

```
ipsecvpnserver_1 | Error: This Docker image must be run in privileged mode.
ipsecvpnserver_1 |
ipsecvpnserver_1 | For detailed instructions, please visit:
ipsecvpnserver_1 | https://github.com/hwdsl2/docker-ipsec-vpn-server
ipsecvpnserver_1 |
elasticbeanstalk_ipsecvpnserver_1 exited with code 1
```

Logs in elasticbeanstalk aren't always easy to read. I added this to `Dockerrun.aws.json`:

```json
"privileged": true,
```

Now it does start locally with success when running `eb local run`, but it's still failing in the cloud.

I've created [an issue on hwdsl2/docker-ipsec-vpn-server](https://github.com/hwdsl2/docker-ipsec-vpn-server/issues/61)

Related documentation:
[Multicontainer Docker Environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html)

Comment: I was able to read the logs when specifying the environment name with `eb logs`, but I get the exact same messages as in the above logs: `Failed to start ECS task...`.

Comment: I needed this quick so I went the non docker way instead and used [hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn](https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn) manually installed on an EC2 Debian 9 instance. If someone gets to make it work on EB, just let me know 